# Lua change current/working dir, Linux (without LFS or any non-std modules)

Tags: lua, dir

I need to change current working dir in lua script for execute specific actions, but i have a trouble with this simple task.
I write test script test.lua :

```
os.execute("cd /usr")
os.execute("ls")
```

But lua test.lua output is:

```
test.lua
```

Current dir doesn't change. What's is wrong? And i can't use LFS or any non-std modules.

---

Thanks to all for explaining it situation. I choose another way : change work dir before run lua script, but i have a lot of troubles with paths which use in scripts and with scripts.

Comment: Changing the current working dir in a child process does not affect the parent process. (Hence the need for `cd` to be a shell built-in instead of a separate program.)

Comment: The [luafilesystem](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) module has `chdir(path)`  and `currentdir()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lua standard library is intended to be both small and portable. Therefore, it is based on the capabilities of the C-standard library for all but a select few functions. It has no function to change directories; that's why libraries like LFS *exist*.

Have you considered that Lua may not be the appropriate language for your needs? If you're doing shell-style scripting work in an environment where you're not allowed to load non-standard modules, perhaps Python or Perl would be better for you. Both of them have extensive standard libraries with a host of features, all without the need to download non-standard modules.

If you want to do any real shell-style scripting in Lua, you need modules. It's that simple. So you should either use external modules or use a different language.

Answer (score 5):

On Unix, `os.execute()` spawns a child process and its children. In
jpjacobs's answer, the first process would execute the shell.

The directory change operation only affects the child process, not the
process in which the Lua interpreter is executing your program.

Comment: Please. If something about the answer is so wrong/useless that it is worth downvoting, at least point out the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply not possible without external libraries. You can use stuff like

```
os.execute("cd /usr/ && ls")
```

Comment: In my case i need something like this:<br/>
os.execute("cd my/specific/path")<br/>
retCode = handler.myFunc(params)<br/>

handler - is loadable module (.so) and i need to change work dir before run myFunc.

Comment: Very useable solution here!

Comment: Amazing! This is really helpful. It's like a hack and it does the job!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of hack, but have you tried creating symbolic links to the folders you need in the current folder, so you don't have to change the current folder at all?

```
os.execute("ln -s /usr/foo") -- link called "foo" in current dir
os.execute("ln -s /usr/bar") -- link called "bar" in current dir

baz = require('foo.baz') -- loading file /usr/foo/baz.lua
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program written using [Zerobranie Lua 5.2](https://studio.zerobrane.com/):

```
local sP = "E:/Documents/Lua-Projs/SVN/ScriptsWireE2"
local a, b, c = os.execute("cd "..sP.."&& dir")
print(a,b,c)
```

And the outpuit:

```
Програма 'lua.exe' пусната в 'E:\Documents\Lua-Projs\ZeroBraineIDE\ZeroBraineProjects' (pid: 8832).
 Volume in drive E is Data
 Volume Serial Number is DE34-ED00

 Directory of E:\Documents\Lua-Projs\SVN\ScriptsWireE2

08-03-2016  18:25    <DIR>          .
08-03-2016  18:25    <DIR>          ..
17-03-2016  18:15    <DIR>          Bridges
07-03-2016  18:21            11 558 license
07-03-2016  18:21                87 readme.md
               2 File(s)         11 645 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  181 729 161 216 bytes free
true    exit    0
Програмата завършена за 0.06 секунди (pid: 8832).
```